# Generating two html tables with titles in first table cell of each row in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, html-table

I need some advise on how to generate two different comparison tables from the same set of data returned from mysql. The first one only needs one row in tbody as shown below.

The second table is tricky to me. I want the titles (brand,country,special functions etc) in the first cell of each row, and I use several foreach loops to get the results, but I think there should be a better way of doing that. Do you have better suggestions on my code?

$first Table:

```
  <table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
         <th></th><th>Product 1</th><th>Product 2</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th></th><td>10</td><td>1</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

$second Table

```
  <table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
         <th></th><th><img src='img.jpg'>Product 1</th><th><img src='img.jpg'>Product 2</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Country</td><td>Japan</td><td>Italy</td>
          <td>Special Functions</td>Adjustable<td></td><td>Rechargeable</td>
          <td>Brand</td>A Brand<td></td><td>B Brand</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

Code:

```
  $sql = "SELECT name,image_url,votes,country,special_functions,brand FROM `products` 
          WHERE name IN (".$in.") GROUP BY name LIMIT 5";

  if ($wpdb->query($sql))  // Wordpress version
  {
    $rows = $wpdb->last_result;

    $first = "";
    $second = "";

    $tablehead = "<table><thead><tr><th></th>";

    $first .= $tablehead;
    $second .= $tablehead;

    foreach($rows as $row)
    { 
      $first .= "<th>".$row->name."</th>";
      $second .= "<th><img src='".$row->image_url."'/>".$row->name."</th>";
    }

    $first .= "</tr></thead></tbody><tr><th></th>";
    $second .= "</tr></thead></tbody><tr>";

    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
      $second .= "<td>country</td>";
    }

    foreach($rows as $row)
    { 
      $first .="<td>".$row->votes."</td>" 
      $second .="<td>".$row->country."</td>";
    }

    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
      $second .= "<td>Special Functions</td>";
    }

    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
      $second .= "<td>".$row->special_functions."</td>";
    }

    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
      $second .= "<td>Brand</td>";
    }

    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
      $second .= "<td>".$row->brand."</td>";
    }

    $endtable = "</tr></tbody></table>";

    $first .= $endtable;
    $second .= $endtable;
  }
```

Comment: You'd better ask for coding advices and suggestions on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You want to do this using pure js only without any external libraries? If not so try angularjs.

Comment: The code you posted does not generate the requested tables.